# Database corruption with MariaDB : Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I'm in an environement setup, running OSX with `MariaDB 10.0.12-MariaDB Homebrew`

I've screwed up the installation so I did completely removed MySQL and MariaDB from my setup and started again.

After finishing installing MariaDB, I've reimported my databases (`innoDB`) via a DB Dump from the production server. It worked fine.
After a reboot, the day after, I can no longer access to the databases :

`Table 'my.table' doesn't exist in engine`

What's causing this and what's the solution ? I do see the structure of my database, but when I try to access it, it gives me this error message.

I did try `mysql-upgrade --force` and deleting `rm ib_logfile1 ib_logfile0`

The data loss is not a problem here, the problem is that I can't spend 30 minutes on re-installing each database each time I do a reboot.

Here's some logs :

```
140730  9:24:13 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140730  9:24:14 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140730  9:24:14 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_slave_pos from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
140730  9:24:14 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1932: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
140730  9:24:14 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.0.12/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.12-MariaDB'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew
140730 16:26:28 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table db/site from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Something has deleted your ibdata1 file where InnoDB keeps the dictionary. Definitely it's not MySQL who does

Comment: Any advice on recovering from this?

Comment: I assume you mean recover table in ibd file which has lost its ibdata1.
In 5.6 you can create an empty table with the same structure and import the tablespace (the old ibd file). Before 5.6 several options are possible: TwinDB's undrop for innodb tool or fix space_id in *.ibd file.

Comment: @akuzminsky could you please write a how to about the recover?

Comment: @AdamTuttle, and for any one coming here, depending on your situation you may find it helpful to call `mysqldump --all-databases > sql_file.sql` , uninstall/reinstall mysql, then call `mysql sql_file.sql`

Comment: @user10089632, if the database is missing an `*.ibd` file for a table that is supposed to exist, `mysqldump` will get an error and generate no data, so don't trust that approach too much.

Comment: I appreciate the video but could you please write a guide instead of an hour-long video?

Comment: @user10089632 : 
backup: `mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > datenbanken-lokal.sql`
restore: `mysql -uroot -p < datenbanken-lokal.sql`

Comment: MariaDB wouldn't stay running in my WinNMP installation (it's happened twice now for some reason), but I was able to get it working by reinstalling WinNMP (renaming the old install to prevent overwrite), Creating a new empty database with the same name, copying over that folder over with the one from my previous installation, and -THANKS TO THIS ANSWER- copying over the ibdata1 file as well.

Answer (score 13):

Ok folks, I ran into this problem this weekend when my OpenStack environment crashed. Another post about that coming soon on how to recover.

I found a solution that worked for me with a SQL Server instance running under the Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.21-MariaDB with Fedora 25 Server as the host.   **Do not listen to all the other posts that say your database is corrupted if you completely copied your old mariadb-server's /var/lib/mysql directory and the database you are copying is not already corrupted.  This process is based on a system where the OS became corrupted but its files were still accessible**.

Here are the steps I followed.

1. Make sure that you have completely uninstalled any current versions of SQL only on the NEW server.    Also, make sure ALL mysql-server or mariadb-server processes on the NEW AND OLD servers have been halted by running:

```bash
service mysqld stop 

# or

service mariadb stop.
```

2. On the NEW SQL server go into the /var/lib/mysql directory and ensure that there are no files at all in this directory.  If there are files in this directory then your process for removing the database server from the new machine did not work and is possibly corrupted.  Make sure it completely uninstalled from the new machine.
3. On the OLD SQL server:

```bash
mkdir /OLDMYSQL-DIR 
cd /OLDMYSQL-DIR
tar cvf mysql-olddirectory.tar /var/lib/mysql
gzip mysql-olddirectory.tar
```

4. Make sure you have sshd running on both the OLD and NEW servers.  Make sure there is network connectivity between the two servers.
5. On the NEW SQL server:

```bash
mkdir /NEWMYSQL-DIR
```

6. On the OLD SQL server:

```bash
cd /OLDMYSQL-DIR
scp mysql-olddirectory.tar.gz <NEW-SERVER-USERNAME>@<NEW-SERVERIP>:/NEWMYSQL-DIR
```

7. On the NEW SQL server:

```bash
cd /NEWMYSQL-DIR
gunzip mysql-olddirectory.tar.gz  OR tar zxvf mysql-olddirectory.tar.gz

# (if tar zxvf doesn't work) 
tar xvf mysql-olddirectory.tar.gz
```

8. You should now have a "mysql" directory file sitting in the NEWMYSQL-DIR.  Resist the urge to run a "cp" command alone with no switches.  It will not work.  Run the following "cp" command and ensure you use the same switches I did.

```bash
cd mysql/
cp -rfp * /var/lib/mysql/
```

9. Now you should have a copy of all of your old SQL server files on the NEW server with permissions in tact.  On the NEW SQL server:

```bash
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

VERY IMPORTANT STEP.  DO NOT SKIP

```bash
rm -rfp ib_logfile
```

10. Now install mariadb-server or mysql-server on the NEW SQL server.  If you already have it installed and/or running then you have not followed the directions and these steps will fail.

FOR MARIADB-SERVER and DNF:

```bash
dnf install mariadb-server
service mariadb restart
```

FOR MYSQL-SERVER and YUM:

```bash
yum install mysql-server
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: This tiny bit "> rm -rfp ib_logfile*" is what fixed the error for me, after I copied the data folder content from my old mysql installation into the new mariadb one

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the error disappeared after I rebooted my OS and restarted MariaDB-server. Strange.

Comment: Worked for me too. At least sometimes the solution can be so easy

Comment: This worked...but then problem reappeared after I tried running a query

Answer (score 1):

This one really sucked.

I tried all of the solutions suggested here but the only thing that worked was to

- create a new database
- run `ALTER TABLE old_db.{table_name} RENAME new_db.{table_name}` on all of the functioning tables
- run `DROP old_db`
- create `old_db` again
- run `ALTER TABLE new_db.{table_name} RENAME old_db.{table_name}` on all the tables in `new_db`

Once you have done that you can finally just create the table again that you previously had.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to:

- backup your database folder from C:\xampp\mysql\data (.frm & .ibd files only corresponding your table names)
- reinstall xampp and recopy DB folder at C:\xampp\mysql\data
- modify my.ini add

  ```
  [mysqld]
  innodb_file_per_table = on
  ```
- then open phpmyadmin (or any other DB viewer as Navicat or MYSQL Workbench) and run

  ```
  ALTER TABLE tbl_name IMPORT TABLESPACE
  ```

  for each table
- Once you can open your tables make a full mysql dump
- delete everything and make a clean install

I know, a lot of work to do that you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem with MariaDB/InnoDB and was able to fix it by

- create the required table in the correct database in another MySQL/MariaDB instance
- stop both servers
- copy .ibd, .frm files to original server
- start both servers
- drop problem table on both servers

Answer (score 0):

This theme required awhile to find results and reasons:

using MaiaDB 5.4. via SuSE-LINUX tumblweed

1. some files in the appointed directory havn't been necessary in any direct relation  with mariadb.  I.e: I placed some hints, a text-file, some bakup-copys somewhere in the same appointed directory for mysql mariadb and this caused endless error-messages and blocking the server from starting.
   Mariadb appears to be very sensible and hostile with the presence of other files not beeing database files(comments,backups,experimantal files etc) .
2. using libreoffice as client then there already this generated much problems with the creation and working on a database and caused some crashes.The crashes eventually produced bad tables.
3. May be because of that or may be because of the presence of not yet deleted but unusable tables !! the mysql mariadb server crashed and
   didn't want to do it' job not even start.

Error message always same : "Table 'some.table' doesn't exist in engine"

But when it started then tables appeared as normal, but it was unpossible to work on them.

So what to do without a more precise Error Message ??
The unusable tables showed up with: "CHECK TABLE" or on the command line of the system with "mysqlcheck " 
So I deleted by filemanager or on the system-level  as root or as allowed user all the questionable files and then problem was solved.

Proposal: the Error Message could be a bit more precisely for example:
"corrupted tables" (which can be found by CHECK TABLE, but only if the server is running) or by mysqlcheck even whe server is not running - but here are  other disturbing files like hints/bakups a.s.o not visible.

ANYWAY it helped a lot to have backup-copies of the original database-files on a backup volume. This helped to check out and test it again and again until solution was found.

Good luck all - Herbert

Answer (score 0):

I had old MySQL and Centos OS (ver 6 I believe) that was not supported.
One day I couldn't access Plesk.
Using Filezilla, I copied files the database files from var/lib/mysql/databasename/
I then purchased a new server with new Centos 8 OS and MariaDB.
In Plesk, I created a new database with the same name as my old one.
Using Filezilla, I then pasted the old database files into the newly created database folder.  I could see the data in phpmyadmin but it was giving errors such as the ones described here.  I happened to have an old sql backup dump file.  I imported the dump file and it overwrote those files.  I then pasted the old files back into var/lib/mysql/databasename/
I then had to do a repair in Plesk. To my suprise. It worked. I had over 6 months of order data restored and I didn't lose anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the db was fully working but the error popped up in workbench without any consequences when I connected to the database.
I found out, that the table not existing in the engine was an old table I deleted from db (and which I did not need anymore).
But somehow I accidentally copied some backup files of this table into the dictionary of the database (.frm and .ibd file) After removing them, the error disappeared.