# Xampp-mysql - "Table doesn't exist in engine" #1932

Tags: mysql, windows

Xampp error after moving xampp folder:

[image]

Apache is running fine:

[image]

as given below image i'm sucess to run apache but unable to run mysql if in case i moved and run xampp both apache and mysql but its shows error which is fresh and it show the error like "Table doesn't exist in engine" #1932 as given up image. please solve the issue anyone help pls

Comment: Check whether you have any luck with this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33925030/5850835) and this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25040628/5850835)

Answer (score 83):

Copy the **ib_logfileXX** and **ibdata** 
file from old mysql/data folder to the new mysql data folder and it will fix the issue

Comment: That worked for me. I installed new version of XAMPP and moved mysql/data and htdocs form the old one to newest one. after this problem appears until I followed your instructions. Thanks :)

Comment: I did that but the problem still exists

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps

Comment: omg thanks man, after 1 day try several ways. Big thanks, brother!!

Comment: Still works for upgrade from mysql5.7.14 to mariadb10.6.5

Comment: What if you deleted the ib_logfileXX files by mistake.

Answer (score 61):

I have faced same issue and sorted using below step.

1. Go to MySQL config file (my file at `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`)
2. Check for the line `innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend`
3. Next check the `ibdata1` file exist under `C:/xampp/mysql/data/`
4. If file does not exist copy the `ibdata1` file from location `C:\xampp\mysql\backup\ibdata1`

hope it helps to someone.

Comment: Copying ibdata1 solved the issue for me, but now I get other errors in phpmyadmin. "Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine".

Comment: This crashed my phpmyadmin using xampp. when i start mysql it's not going start

Comment: file exist in my case but error also exist in phpmyadmin and php site

Comment: I often see this problem. Copy backup folder and rename as data and after replace the old ibdata1 100% fixed my mysql problem

Answer (score 16):

If you have copied & Pasted files from an old backup folder to new then its simple.
Just copy the old `ibdata1` into your new one. You can find it from `\xampp\mysql\data`
And restart your mysql.

Answer (score 12):

## Don't copy `ibdata1` file

This occurred to me when I take all files from the backups folder. There is a file you should not copy with other folders and files, called **`ibdata1`**.

Comment: This means we cannot copy the table folder only for backup or other purposes. It needs to be copied all data folder instead.

Comment: Works perfectly, it seems that only copying `ib_logfile1` & `ib_logfile0` from backup 
folder and deleting all `.info` files is sufficient

Answer (score 11):

You could:

1. Rename data folder to **data-old**
2. Create new folder and set name to  **data**
3. Copy **backup** folder in **data** folder
4. Copy **ibdata1** in data-old to **data** folder
5. **Restart** MySQL and Apache

> After solving the problems, get output power from the database

Comment: copying ibdata1 from old folder bring the problem back. if i delete this file then run mysql it is created automaticall and problem is solved.

Answer (score 10):

I have faced same issue but copying the `xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1` was not solved my problem, because I install new version of xampp, if you upgrading your xampp first make backup from all `htdocs` and `mysql` folder, in my case I just backup the all xampp to the new folder like `old-xampp` then install new xampp and then you need do the following steps before starting your new xampp servers:

1. Backup the `phpmyadmin` folder and `ibdata1` from your new installation form this location `xampp\mysql\data`.
2. Then Go to your old xampp folder `old-xampp\mysql\data` and copy the `ibdata1` file and `phpmyadmin` from old location.
3. Then open your new xampp folder `xampp\mysql\data` and past them there.
4. Start the xampp servers.

Answer (score 8):

1. stop mysql
2. copy xampp\mysql\data\ib* from old server to new server
3. start mysql

Answer (score 2):

I had previously moved my mysql directory and forgot to change ALL references to the old location in \mysql\bin\my.ini.

change these three lines:

```
datadir = "/programs/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_home_dir = "/programs/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "/programs/xampp/mysql/data"
```

Change "/programs/xampp/mysql/data" to new location
this one was commented but I changed it anyways

```
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "/programs/xampp/mysql/data"
```

Comment: Also check @Jay Momaya's answer, happenned to me again and that solved it too

Comment: This is the perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

ok step one you can copy from your old xampp xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 and step two paste to your xampp new xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 ,
and than open your xampp controller and stop mysql and start again.

i tried this and is work for me

Answer (score 2):

## 100% working solution

1. **Stop MySQL and Apache and quit Xampp**.
2. Make a backup of the "data" folder.

> C:\xampp\mysql\data

3. Copy all the files from this folder

> C:\xampp\mysql\backup
> 4. Paste and replace to

```
C:\xampp\mysql\data
```

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for **Ubuntu** users:

1. Copy a database (e.g. from the external disk backup).

   `sudo cp -r /media/some_user/mysql/some_database/ /opt/lampp/var/mysql/`

NOTE: from this moment on, the database already appears in PHPMyAdmin, but if you click on it, the tables still do not appear

2. Change the owner to `mysql` (because when copying the owner it was changed to `root`)

   `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql some_database/`

NOTE: from this moment the name of the tables appears but you can't see their structure or data - it shows the error "#1932 - Table 'some_database.some_table' doesn't exist in engine"

3. Copy the `ibdata1` file and also change the owner.

   `sudo mv ibdata1 ibdata1_old`

   `sudo cp /media/some_user/mysql/ibdata1 /opt/lampp/var/mysql/`

   `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql ibdata1`
4. Restart XAMPP

   `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Comment: Legend, Thank you man, saved my day!! i copied the old ibdata1  to mysql in the new installation folder and made it owner and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the content of `backups` folder into `data` folder. This worked for me.
- After this you have to reconfigure innodb files of your existent databases

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer little bit more, for fellow programmers, to understand how it helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you explain your second point? Because first point worked for me and now I lost all the data. I can see the list of tables but when I click on any, says table does not exists in the engine.

Comment: @VipulHadiya did you find any solution? I am currently stuck with the same problem as yours.

Comment: @RajuAhmed No, fortunately, I had backup of every single database so I have deleted them all and imported all SQL one by one.

Comment: @VipulHadiya Yes - this is, also, the best solution I have found also but very time consuming. Having gone through this about 3 times in the past few years. I'm looking for an explanation of how the tables get deleted in the first place and whether there are maintenance steps I can take to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had a backup of my `C:\xampp\mysql\data` folder. But integrating it with the newly installed `xampp` had issues. So I located the `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` file and directed `innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"` to my backed-up data folder and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solution works for me. After pasting your old mysql/data directory to your new xampp, Check if ibdata1 has all the permissions required by the current user otherwise try to grant the permissions. Then "Empty Session Data" in your phpmyadmin, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the above answers and yet failed, first try to fix your db by running this command,

**mysqlcheck --repair my_db_name -u root -p**

And then if issue fixed,

If not fixed and you have a backup of the table with you and not able to import it to the PHPMyAdmin, do the following.

**1. Go to xampp\mysql\data\database_folder**

**2. Delete the files (with extension .frm and .ibd) starting with your table name. Eg: my_table.frm, my_table.ibd**

**3. Import your table**

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66804621
helpful

If you are just moving your DB from one folder to another folder, but your InnoDB tables no longer work, because they can't be found and the error message "Table does not exist in the engine" is displayed, then these pair of SQL statements can be as quick as helpful:

```
ALTER TABLE __yourtable_name__ DISCARD TABLESPACE ;

ALTER TABLE __yourtable_name__ IMPORT TABLESPACE ;
```

In pratice, the .IDB file is detached from .FRM file and then bound again, so that table contents turn into readable.

It worked in my case. Hope yours too.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. stop mysql and apache server
2. copy backup folder
3. copy database folders from data folder to backup copy folder
4. delete ibdata1 from backup copy folder
5. copy ibdata1 from data folder to backup copy folder
6. delete data folder
7. rename backup copy folder to data folder
8. restart the xampp server

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried every possible solution above and still are not able to solve, you may be able to try this:

##### only if you have taken a backup previously

###### For this, consider:

- database name is dbnm
- the table that is throwing the error is tbnm
- Go to the backup/dbnm/ folder.
- Copy the tbnm.ibd and tbnm.frm files.
- Go to mysql/bin/data/dbnm/
- Paste the copied files, and replace the original.
  See if it works!!

Answer (score 0):

copy from your old xampp  `xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1`
and
copy `theNameOfdatabase` from `xampp\mysql\data\theNameOfdatabase`
then
Then  paste to your xampp new `xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1`,
and `xampp\mysql\data\theNameOfdatabase`

and than open your xampp controller and stop mysql and start again.

basically you are replacing the ibdata1
and
copying your database file from your old xammp

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all file which start from ib from old **mysql/old-data** folder and paste all of these on **mysql/data** folder

Answer (score -2):

For me I removed whole `data` folder ( and took a backup ) from `xampp\mysql\` and pasted `data` folder of previous one here which solved my problem...

Comment: Your solution delete my entire database table

Comment: Please before you do this, backup the content of the data folder somewhere. Mysql creates folders that keeps files needed by your databases to work.