# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Today I run MySQL and MySQL is not working, giving the following error in the console:

```
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:30:43 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

When checking the "/xampp/mysql/data/mysql_error.log" file I get:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-16  8:30:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-16  8:30:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 47072; transaction id 8
2021-03-16  8:30:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-16  8:30:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-16  8:30:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210316  8:30:42
2021-03-16  8:30:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Is that the end of the log?

Comment: Where did the first log come from? What does "run MySQL" mean in this context?

Comment: I have fixed the same issue , see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68031369

Answer (score 5):

Delete these file and restart mysql service.

```
/var/lib/mysqld/ib_logfile0
/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control
```

Comment: Hey, great solution! Works for me in Xampp 8 for Windows.