# XAMPP Error Launching mySql last log "Server socket created on IP: '::'."

Tags: mysql, xaml

mysql wont start when with this error log :

```
16:52:59  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
16:52:59  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
16:53:01  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
16:53:01  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
16:53:01  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:53:01  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:53:01  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:53:01  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:53:01  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
16:53:01  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

more over, this log showed belom brom MySQL log :

```
2022-10-25 16:52:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.  // this is 2 prev launch sesion
2022-10-25 16:52:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'. // this is also prev launch sesion
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Main\Aplikasi\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Main\Aplikasi\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 561855; transaction id 973
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Main\Aplikasi\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-25 16:54:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'. // end of log
```

last time i used it just for view testing my project (No create, update, or delete on my database. only read my database)

I've been trying to change port number, changing mysql/data to mysql/old_data, running in admin mode.
there's no further explanation after server socket created IP ::

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late, today I got the same issue with my Xampp server
and I find a solution it might work for you.
source: [MySQL shutdown unexpectedly on XAMPP - Server socket created on IP: '::'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388844/mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-server-socket-created-on-ip)

Comment: thanks, i reinstalled xampp and restore my database