# Xampp MySQL shutdown unexpectedly Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled

Tags: mysql, xampp

Just started up Xampp today and when I turn on my SQL, it simply turns off again and tells me that MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

Here is the log:

```
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 639553085; transaction id 596387
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-22  9:28:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Answer (score 17):

I have fixed the issue. From xampp/mysql/backup/ folder i copied all files in to xampp/mysql/data/ That solved the issue.

look like the issue cause database innodb structure conflict

Answer (score 0):

If in the `mysql_error.log` mentioned an error like follows.

```
[ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

Try deleting `aria_log.#######` file in the xampp\mysql\data.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix this problem –

Stop the XAMPP server, MySQL and Apache
Create a backup of the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder using a compression software
Rename the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder to “/xampp/mysql/data-old”
Create a new folder and name it “/xampp/mysql/data”
Copy all folders from the “/xampp/mysql/backup” and paste it to the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder, which you have just created
Copy all the databases from the “/xampp/mysql/data-old” folder and paste it to the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder
Finally copy the “ibdata1” and all of the log files including “ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 ” from “/xampp/mysql/data-old” and paste it to the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder
Start MySQL from the XAMPP control panel
Go to phpMyAdmin to check if all the databases are available and running properly

- i’ve successfully fixed this way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The above answer worked, but later I got a "table doesn't exist in engine error", then this answer helped me out.
[Xampp-mysql - "Table doesn't exist in engine" #1932](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759870/xampp-mysql-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine-1932)

Comment: This could be a comment, please add a comment instead of answer.

Comment: I'm unable to comment due to lack of reputations