# Mysql Table 'db.table' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu and after restarting the mysql server it gives an error - Table 'db.table' doesn't exist in engine
Table exists, frm / ibd is in place and has owner mysql
Before that I did Optimize table
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'db.table' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: MySql is case-sensitive on Linux but case-insensitive on Windows. I hope you're taking care of the case when passing the table name in query. Are u running the query on terminal or workbench?
Also, can u share the exact query you're executing?

Comment: @UrvashiSoni
this happens before any query to the database, phpmyadmin writes that the table is "in use"

Comment: Full error text:
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'db.table' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759870/xampp-mysql-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine-1932/44799226