# Copy mariaDB aaaa.table to aaaa.table2 and use both

Tags: mariadb

aaa Table in use, aaa2 Table backed up a few days ago

I copied it to "cp aaa aaa2".
I have accidentally changed the aaa table data.
aaa can not kill because it has recent data.

aaa2 is an "in use" 1932 error in phpmyadmin.

How can I recover aaa2?

```
Error message:
Error: Table 'db.aaa2' doesn't exist in engine
status: Operation failed
```

The engine is InnoDB.

======================================================

I go ahead and add more.

```
aaa.table AUTO_INCREMENT 10000
aaa2.table AUTO_INCREMENT 95000
```

I made another mistake.
I did not mysqldump aaa(1) and copied the file elsewhere.

And
Renamed aaa2(2) to aaa(2).
aaa(2) worked fine.

There was a problem.
I dumped aaa(2) to mysqldump and deleted the file.
I copied aaa(1) again, but it does not recover because of an "in use" error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25039927/1531971

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`, you *cannot simply copy the file*.

Plan A:  Dump and reload (careful with the table name).

Plan B:  Use "transportable tablespaces".

Comment: Please let me know more.