# Adding Generated Columns Crashes MariaDB

Tags: docker, mariadb, generated-columns

I am experiencing a strange bug with generated columns and MariaDB running in a Docker container.

The image I'm using is `mariadb:10`.

I have been trying to add generated columns. The first column I add works fine; the second I add crashes the container and destroys the table.

Here's the first column that is working:

```sql
ALTER TABLE program
    ADD is_current tinyint AS (
        IF (
            status IN ('active', 'suspended')
            AND start_date >= NOW(),
            1,
            0
        )
    );
```

This one works just fine. The following SQL crashes the container:

```sql
ALTER TABLE program
    ADD is_covered tinyint AS (
        IF (
            status IN ('active', 'suspended')
            AND start_date <= NOW(),
            1,
            0
        )
    );
```

After restarting the container, I get the following errors:

```sql
SELECT * FROM program;
```

> [42S02][1932] Table 'my_local.program' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

```sql
repair table my_local.program;
```

> Table 'my_local.program' doesn't exist in engine / operation failed

Following the directions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039927/database-corruption-with-mariadb-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine) I checked in the container for the existence of the `ibdata1` file. It exists, as do the table's `.ibd` and `.rfm` files.

I have not been able to fix this; I had to drop the table and re-create it and re-import the data.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear.

Comment: the only difference is `<=` versus `>=`?

Comment: From the [mariadb documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/): "*The `ALTER TABLE` statement has limited support for generated columns. ... - It does not support adding a `VIRTUAL` generated column with the `ADD` clause if the same statement is also adding other columns if `ALGORITHM` is not set to `COPY`. See [MDEV-17468](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17468) for more information.*" - Could this be related?

Comment: Edited to change MySQL to MariaDB. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and it has been implementing its own code since then. You should consider MariaDB to be a distinct database product from MySQL. There are more and more incompatibilities between these two products introduced in each release.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @Barmar yes, there is actually some more logic I'd like to include but I didn't get that far before the table crashed...

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin. I should have fixed that myself.

Comment: @ysth output is `10.5.10-MariaDB-1:10.5.10+maria~focal`

Answer (score 2):

Checking the [reference for MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for generated columns I find that

> Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are
> permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in
> tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of
> the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic
> and fail this definition: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW().

This is also true of MySQL 5.7.

When I attempted to create your generated column with MySQL 8 I got this message:

> Error Code: 3763. Expression of generated column 'is_covered' contains a disallowed function: now.

I note, however, that you are using `mariadb:10`. Although it is derived from MySQL, MariaDB is now effectively a different product.

The [MariaDB reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) for generated columns says: (for 10.2.1 onwards):

> ```
> Non-deterministic built-in functions are supported in expressions for not indexed VIRTUAL generated columns. 
>
> Non-deterministic built-in functions are not supported in expressions for PERSISTENT or indexed VIRTUAL generated columns.
> ```

So, If you have MySQL you can't do this at all. If you have MariaDB 10.2.1+ you should be able to do it with certain limitations.

In any case, you should get an error message, not a crashed table. I suggest you check the MariaDB [bug reports](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-community-bug-reporting/), and submit one if this is not already there.