# xampp mysql and phpmyadmin dont work

Tags: mysql, xampp

yesterday i worked with my xampp and i used apache and mysql services.
Today i want to start mysql service and did not worked. I try to search on forums a solution but i cant find anything, so i ask you.

In the log file i find this message after the mysql stopped working:

```
2015-10-29 12:04:02 148c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-29 12:04:02 148c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
151029 12:04:02 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_index_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
151029 12:04:02 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"mysql"."innodb_index_stats"', ignored.
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
151029 12:04:02 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1665234
151029 12:04:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
151029 12:04:02 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
151029 12:04:02 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
151029 12:04:02 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

Can you help me fix this issue?

Comment: Check it please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782451/mysql-in-xampp-starts-and-stops-in-five-seconds

Comment: I tried that but none of then could help...

Comment: Have you considered deleting and reinstalling your xampp?

Comment: I used msql backup files and that solved tha problem.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I copied all files in `xampp/mysql/backup/` to `xampp/mysql/data/`.

Comment: This worked for me also. Could you help me to understand how it worked?

Comment: its worked, but I have to make some configuration to make phpmyadmin work

Comment: @AngrejKumar can you elaborate a bit more on what further configuration you have made?

Comment: Can you explain the cause of this issue?

Comment: I'm now getting a new error 'Table doesn't exist in engine'. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Occured on XAMPP v3.3.0, fixed with this solution

Comment: Worked for me also - After a brand new install of XAMPP Version: 8.1.12 and an upgrade to phpmyadmin 5.2.1, before creating any databases, I clicked on the "User Accounts" tab and got a message indicating 'db' was corrupt.  This fixed it!  Thanx.

Answer (score 16):

I had this similar issue today and was able to solve it by:

1. Close the XAMPP control panel
2. delete the following files under /xampp/mysql/data:

   - aria_log.**1
   - aria_log_control
   - ib_logfile0
   - ib_logfile1
   - ibdata1
   - ibtmp1
   - mysqld.pid
3. AND modify the multi-master.info and delete all its content then save the file.
4. open the Xampp and run mysql again.

Comment: This worked for me! but, i not have files: ibtmp1 and mysqld.pid, just delete others and ok, it's work!

Comment: MySQL started but I'm getting this error now: Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine. Any idea?

Comment: Don't do this as deleting the ibdata1 means no recovery for all your data

Comment: MariaDB doesn't create files to be annoying. `aria_log*` files will recovery if a crash occured during a table modification. `ib_logfile*` DOES CONTAIN YOUR DATA until a purge operation is done. `ibdata1` is the system tablespace containing essential to the operation of MariaDB. The most likely outcome you have by doing this is dataloss but just enough visibility of tables to pretend you haven't lost anything.

Comment: "Directly editing or moving the redo logs can cause corruption, and should never normally be attempted." ref [official redo logs page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-redo-log/)

Answer (score 11):

As additional to the correct answer, you don't need to delete all the files inside `xampp/mysql/data/`, just replace with whatever inside `xampp/mysql/backup/` will do. Cheers

Comment: This worked great for me and saved my data!