# MySQL won't run when i am using XAMPP server

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is the error log for the MySQL when I run it on XAMPP. I don't know how to fix it, it's always stuck on attempting to start MySQL service..

I tried changing the port but the result is still the same. 
also tried re-installing but the problem is still the same

thank you in advance.the error i get is as follows

```
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
    Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
    2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

    2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
    2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
    2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
    2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
    2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

and this are the config for mySQL. Note: I didn't make any changes in it.

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: you could also try to reinstall it, have you tried it?

Comment: i have tried re installing it and still the same

Answer (score 33):

It took me 2 days to find the solution. Here our friend Francis posted the solution which worked for me. I think the problem was corrupted files of mysql:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33413223/9106762

Simply navigate to your xampp folder -> mysql -> backup -> copy all files and folders inside it and paste them into xampp/mysql/data directory.

This worked for me perfectly (I tried to change my.ini, ports, resetting the services,... before but nothing worked). Hope it helps others too.

Comment: It worked for me. As you mentioned I've also tried changing ports but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: This absolutely work, after looking at the logs from the mysql error log, windows event viewer i finally found the problem.. The db had crashed and unable to repair, to fix this i've to copy backup and paste it back in data folder for mysql table to be fixed.

Comment: This worked for me as well. +1 But I think it would be better to get rid of XAMPP at all, it corrupts itself pretty often...

Comment: @Pagenotfound Exactly, now I moved to Mac Laptop and I'm using MAMP, it's much better that XAMPP, also for windows and linux users I suggest using Laragon.

Comment: Maaan thanks! That's definitely my case too. Seems like some data was crashed after electricity shutdown. I did dozens "port-checks", hyper-V turnoffs, reboots and I almost start to reinstall XAMPP but luckily did one more try in search and got you recommendation! Definetly special case that should be accepted too!

Answer (score 1):

To me, this looks like the offending line:

`2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.`

It looks like MySQL isn't binding to your localhost, and therefore can't bind to a port on said host, and won't start because of that.

Check your config file in MySQL to make sure it's set up correctly. Failing that, a fresh install of xampp to restore defaults should do the trick.

EDIT:

For more info here, as far as I can tell, if you're using IPv6 then `::1` should be the loopback address for localhost. I'm not entirely sure what just `::` is.

Comment: i tried re-installing it but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Perhaps try checking config? If you could post it here, that would help.

Comment: `# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6` Depending on whether you're using IPv4/6, uncomment one of these lines.

Comment: I just tried right now but the problem and error log didn't change. :(

Answer (score 1):

- Rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
- Create a new folder mysql/data
- Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new mysql/data folder
- Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (skipping
  the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
- Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it
  inside mysql/data folder
  Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel
  I tried this serveral time and it always worked for me..