# Table not in engine - InnoDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, xampp, innodb, data-loss

Today I ran into an issue where the XAMPP MariaDB wouldn't start, no matter what.
The logs looked like this:

```
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 5912
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-01-29 13:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 2358558; transaction id 10636
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-29 13:14:06 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'
```

So I tried the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63623364/22477932

Now my Database starts again, however all of my tables "don't exist in engine". According to some answers to the fix, there shouldnt be any data loss.

I believe it has something to do with the logfiles, but I don't know and couldnt find much on how to  "restore" them.

Any help regarding this is welcome. I do still have the files within the data folder.

This is how the log looks now for anyone who is interested:

```
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 6336
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11451
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Xamp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-01-29 13:23:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-01-29 13:23:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2024-01-29 13:23:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-29 13:23:28 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\plugin'
2024-01-29 13:23:28 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\servers'
2024-01-29 13:23:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Don't trust answers on the internet. What works (or is claimed to work) may not be your problem or a correct solution in your scenario. Don't take steps you cannot revert. You've lost data, restore from backup.

Comment: Oh no, I do know what I did there - I did make backups. And there was no real data in there. I just wanted to know if anyone knows a solution, or if there is a possible recovery. :) But Yes ofc ur right, don't trust the internet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. here is how I fixed it.

Goto your `xampp install dir` > `mysql`:

1. Rename `data` folder as `data_original`
2. take a copy of `backup` and rename as `data`
3. Copy all folders (only folders) from `data_original` to `data`
4. Copy `ibdata1` from `data_original` to `data`

** PROTECT THAT `backup` FOLDER AT ALL COST, YOU'LL NEED IT AGAIN  **