# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, port

**I don't know what's happening to mysql , it doesn't start up. IT was working fine yesterday but today it won't start. I haven't installed any program nor messed up with any settings's. Tried changing ports but won't help**

below is the log report and i have no idea whats it is about. Please help me i have a project to submit and mysql won't start up.

```
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
    160112 17:31:16 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 33725452 and 33725452 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 42635885 in the ib_logfiles!
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
    160112 17:31:17 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
    160112 17:31:18 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    160112 17:31:18 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    160112 17:31:18 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 42635885
    160112 17:31:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    160112 17:31:18 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql in xampp starts and stops in five seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782451/mysql-in-xampp-starts-and-stops-in-five-seconds)

Comment: also please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Comment: when you run your code what is the error ? what error show on you browser

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\xampp\htdocs\BOT-BandOfTravelers\db_connect.php on line 6
connection to database failedNo connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.